# PHP grid/table Modal Popup Duplication

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using PHP to create a grid/table for user entry and all works fine. The problem is that one of the text boxes has a modal popup with some additional information. It works fine if there is only 1 row, but when I add 2 or more, the Modal options are then posted above the table and the popup does not work.
Any ideas?

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
$(function () {

    $("#MyDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 340,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                $('#popup').val($('#year').val() + " " + $('#week').val() + " " + $('#day').val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            $('#year').val("");
            $('#week').val("");
            $('#day').val("");
        }
    });

    $("#popup").click(function () {
        $("#MyDialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

**PHP**

> ```
> $line = $_GET["Line"];  
> if($line == 0){$line=1;}  
> for($i=1;$i<=$line;$i++)
> {
> ```

**Code**

> ```
> <tr>
> <td><div align="center"><input type="text" id="type" title="X1" name="txttypeofunit<?=$i;?>" size="12"></div></td>
> <td><input type="text" id="description" title="X2" name="txtunitdescription<?=$i;?>" size="15"></td>
> <td><input type="text" id="manu" title="X3" name="txtmanufacturer<?=$i;?>" size="12"></td>
> <td><div align="center"><input type="text" id="model" title="X4<?=$i;?>" size="12"></div> </td>
> <td align="right"><input type="text" id="serial" title="X4" name="txtserial<?=$i;?>" size="12"></td>
> <td align="right"><input type="text" id="tags" title="X5" name="txtyearbuilt<?=$i;?>" size="12"></td>
> <div id="MyDialog" title="Running Time Of Unit <?=$i;?>" >
>       Months a year?   <input type="text" id="year" size="5" /> - M/Y <br>
>         Days a week?   <input type="text" id="week" size="5" /> - D/W <br>
>         Hours a day?   <input type="text" id="day" size="5" /> - H/D            
>     </div>
>     <div>
> <td align="right"><input type="text" id="popup" id="cool" title="How many months in a year is the unit in use? 1 - 12" size="12">    
> </div>
> <td><input type="text" id="refig" title="X6" name="txtrefrigerationtype<?=$i;?>" size="12"></td>
> <td><div align="center"><input type="number" id="input" title="X7"
> ```